# Error installing packages using chocolatey behind virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, chocolatey

I have my windows virtual machine in virtualbox, Internet connectivity works fine. I installed chocolatey windows package manager using https://chocolatey.org/install.

However installation of packages failing:

[image]

I tried `nodejs`, `visualstudiocode` ... Always same

Comment: You might want to upgrade Virtualbox (or rollback) - there was a known issue with a particular version that had issues with SSL communication.

Comment: More details at https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16084 and https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1029